# Открыть файл ассемблер

Tags: linux, ассемблер

Как на ассемблере открывать файл и записать туда строку? Я понимаю, что должно быть что-то вроде:

```
movl $0, %eax
int $0x80
```

Но какие параметры нужно передавать, теряюсь в догадках.

**UPD**
 Получил:

```
.file   "c.cpp"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "w"
.LC1:
    .string "myfile.txt"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $48, %rsp
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $1819043144, -32(%rbp)
    movl    $1870078063, -28(%rbp)
    movl    $681074, -24(%rbp)
    movl    $13, -36(%rbp)
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    call    fopen
    movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)
    movl    -36(%rbp), %eax
    movslq  %eax, %rdx
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rcx
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $1, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    fwrite
    movl    $0, %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rdx
    je  .L2
    call    __stack_chk_fail
.L2:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите код, который делает gcc -S для программы c open(), write() и вызывайте аналогично (естественно линкуйте c libc).

Comment: спасибо, теперь уже можно разобраться только вот еще один вопросик назрел что означает .cfi (обновил вопрос)

Answer (score 2):

Тут есть два способа делать системные вызовы из ассемблера.

**Подход 1** - тот, что предложил [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp): линкуем все дело с помощью gcc с glibc и тупо вызываем ее функции (типа open(), fopen() и т.д.), загнав предварительно в стек в нужном порядке нужные аргументы. Только зачем тогда возиться с ассемблером, когда то же можно легко и просто сделать из Си.

**Подход 2**. Вызываем непосредственно системные  вызовы минуя glibc с помощью упомянутого Вами прерывания int 80h (так только на х86, на х86_64 все несколько по-другому). Перед этим в регистр eax заносится номер системного вызова (open - 5, read - 3), а параметры поочередно в регистры ebx, ecx, edx, esx, edi (подробнее смотри [здесь](http://bluemaster.iu.hio.no/edu/dark/lin-asm/syscalls.html)). Далее int 80h. В eax будет находиться возвращаемое ядром значение (если < 0 - содержит код ошибки).

Подробнее рекомендую смотреть [книжку Столярова](http://www.stolyarov.info/books/asm_unix). Она хоть содержит описание NASM и интеловского синтаксиса, но при наличии сообразилки приложить ее сведения к gas не составит труда.

Comment: Очень полезная ссылка, спасибо